# kotlin \n adds an extra space in output

Tags: kotlin

So i have a string text = "" and when i want to increment i use text+= "something", but i need to make a break line because i will write that text a couple times repeated, but when i do text+="\n" it adds the spaces between the "something" texts but after that it adds another space that i dont want.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to remove the `\n` character at the last iteration of your loop, otherwise, code wise, this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Per: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors , "Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly."

Comment: can i do that by adding an if condition?

Comment: you can just do `lines.joinToString("\n")`

Answer (score 1):

I would not do it iteratively. So instead of using a loop, you can use [joinToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) for that, like this:

```java
lines.joinToString(separator = "\n")
```

Comment: that method doesnt work for me

Comment: sorry, had a typo. works now?

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @GonçaloGrilo: you should accept this answer, as it is the correct one (short and avoids an unnecessary loop).

Answer (score 0):

```
val result = string.substringBeforeLast("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help!

```
fun main() {
        var string=""
        for (line in 0 until 4){
            string += "Something"
            if (line!=3){
                string+="\n"
            }
        }
        print(string)
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.